# How to change color of a link on click on a Pagination using CSS3

Tags: html, css

I want to change the color of href once it is being clicked. I can use the active property just for one of the links. I have also used `a:visited` property of a link but this changes color for all the colors.

Pagination code

```
<div class="centerPagination">
    <div class="pagination">
        <a href="#">&laquo;</a>
        <a href="#" class="active">1</a>
        <a href="#">2</a>
        <a href="#">3</a>
        <a href="#">4</a>
        <a href="#">5</a>
        <a href="#">&raquo;</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* Pagination */
.centerPagination {
text-align: center;
}

.pagination {
display: inline-block;
}

.pagination a {
color: black;
float: left;
padding: 10px 10px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
transition: background-color .3s;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: white;
height: 6.5px;
padding-top: 5px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.pagination a.active {
background-color: #317D82;
color: white;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.pagination a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #FFFACD; 
}

/* .pagination a:visited {
 background-color: #317D82;
} */

.pagination a:first-child {
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.pagination a:last-child {
 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: a:visited changes all the links because they all link to the same (href="#")

Comment: is JavaScript an option?

Comment: Are you looking for `:active`? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/VbXGJB

Comment: @cjs you are right. But the color stays with that button.

Comment: @andreim. I am not sure because I am going to invoke some JS methods for the pagination itself to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm working on a small enough site, I sometimes add in a custom `selected` class.

Example css class :

```
.nav li.selected a {
    color: #99B2FF;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

.. and then just edit where the selected class is added in the html nav depending on the page.

Example html:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">In Brief</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li class="selected"><a>Money</a></li>  <!---selected--->
    <li><a href="workjack.html">Work</a></li>   
    <li><a href="sportscolm.html">Sport</a></li>
    <li><a href="culturejack.html">Culture</a></li> 
    <li><a href="lifestylerachel.html">Lifestyle</a></li>
    <li><a href="environmentcolm.html">Environment</a></li>         
</ul>
```

The above example was used in a group college project. It still has an active link so you can [take a look here](http://multimedia.dcu.ie/~gallenr2/worldnews/index.html)

Comment: It looks good, but the issue is that once you clicked in any of the links the color on the link stays. Meaning it doesn't change back to white from blue after being selected.

Comment: @Mike no it doesn't there's other css there for  the :visited state. The currently-selected is a darker blue. It's not that obvious but it was designed that way

Comment: @Mike  (update to earlier comment) a better [mimimal] example : I have taken out the :visited state (not active state) css and just left what's above, and the :hover state (turns blue on hover, red on selected). Note that only the index and the about work in this example - it's just for demo  purposes. http://project.rachelgallen.com/index.html – Rachel Gallen

Comment: There you go, this is what I was looking for. Now I can only invoke a JS method to do the pagination for me. Thanks Rachel. I accept your answer as accepted.

Comment: Happy I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the **while** the link is being clicked: select `:active` pseudo-class.

If you want to change the color **after** the link has been clicked on, use `:visited` pseudo-class.
And if you change your anchors, so they all have different `href`'s, they'll avoid getting in the `:visited` state all at once.